# How can I place the navigation control of Woocommerce Product Gallery on the right side>

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to style a custom theme for WordPress, currently, I am stuck at the single product page, where I can not work away with CSS or WooCommerce hooks and functions, to move the thumbnails from under the main picture to the left side, aligning vertically.

Here is an image that might describe my goals better.

[image: This is what I am looking for]

Comment: You should change the woocommerce templates, I think the template you want to edit is  product-image.php, you should copy the template file to your custom theme to override it without messing with the original one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky, but hopefully it can help (I just did this for a recent site), but it's all CSS based. You may have to play with it in your instance.

The idea is to move the `.woocommerce-product-gallery` over a percentage and then absolutely position the `.flex-control-nav` to the left of the gallery. Setting it as a flex parent will stack the `li` (thumbnails). I created a very rough version of what Woocommerce outputs. You'll most likely need to make each selector more specific like `body.single-product .product .woocommerce-product-gallery`

This will get you close to what you want. If you run the snippet, view it fullscreen.

```css
.product {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.woocommerce-product-gallery {
  width: 33.3333% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  left: 8.333%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-control-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -25.0513347023%;
  width: calc(25% - 40px);
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.flex-control-nav li {
  margin-bottom: 23px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}

div.summary {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  clear: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="product-1234" class="product">
  <div class="woocommerce-product-gallery woocommerce-product-gallery--with-images woocommerce-product-gallery--columns-5 images" data-columns="4" style="opacity: 1; transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in-out 0s;">
    <a href="#" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__trigger"></a>

    <div class="flex-viewport" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 544px;">
      <figure class="woocommerce-product-gallery__wrapper" style="width: 400%; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
        <div data-thumb="https://via.placeholder.com/500x400" data-thumb-alt="" class="woocommerce-product-gallery__image flex-active-slide" style="width: 467px; margin-right: 0px; float: left; display: block;">
          <a href="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400x500" class="wp-post-image" alt="" title="Placeholder" data-caption=""></a>
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
    <ol class="flex-control-nav flex-control-thumbs">
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" class="flex-active" draggable="false"></li>
      <li><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100" draggable="false"></li>
    </ol>
  </div>

  <div class="summary entry-summary">
    <h1 class="product_title entry-title">Product Title</h1>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!